# Material-UI custom redux-form-material-ui RadioGroup <Radio /> control prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I would like to compose a custom RadioGroup element as seen in this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/woo83lzy68). Ideally I'd like to have an Avatar as a sibling to the radio element of the control pro.  Im stumbling on this JS warning or at least understanding the root of why inputRef cant spread to this element.

*React does not recognize the `inputRef` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `inputref` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.*

As you can see in the example the custom control prop breaks the RadioGroup functionality making it multi-select. Is this custom Radio component possible?

```
    `<Field name="bestFramework" component={RadioGroup}>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <span>
            <Radio value="react" />
            <Avatar
              alt="react"
              src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/53/53058.svg"
            />
          </span>
        }
        label="React"
        value="react"
      />
      <Radio value="angular" label="Angular" />
      <Radio value="ember" label="Ember" />
    </Field>`
```